# How to properly animate UIView animation?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

I have an UIScrollView which has 7 UIViews as subviews.

Using `UIView.animate` method, I am making subviews transition from left to end of the content size of `UIScrollView`.

```
func animateScrollView(){
    if stopAnimation {
        print("Scroll View Animation Stopped")
    } else {
        print("Animating Scroll View")
        featureScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: false)
        featureScrollView.delegate = nil
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear, .repeat], animations: {
            self.featureScrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.subViewWidth * CGFloat(7)  - CGFloat(0), y: 0.0)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I want this animation to repeat right after last-UIView of previous loop starts to move. So, the sliding `UIView`s will be always sliding without blank spaces at the end.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: `setContentOffset(_:animated)`?

Comment: Getting same behavior.